# Email notifications from site aren't sent

Tags: postfix, email-server, ubuntu-16.04

I set up from scratch an `Ubuntu Server 16.04` and there I setup a `Moodle` site with `Apache2`.  The problem is that all the email notifications from the `Moodle` don't work.

When I was installing Ubuntu, I choose to install the mail server:

I chose `Internet Site`

[image]

and then I filled the input with my site name `mysite.com`

[image]

Am I filled something wrong here? Should I contact with the administrator of the computer room to ask him?

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose why emails are not being sent, in your situation (full control over the system), it is especially important to distinguish whether this is at application or system/email level.

You gave us very little details about your issue.

Consider:

- What application logs says (`Moodle`)
- **What is happening in `/var/log/mail.log` when you expect email should be sent**
- Is your email server able to send any email, anywhere
- Is your email server able to send locally (i.e. to system user)
- Is your public IP address listed on DNS blacklists (check [here](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx))? If so, it is unlikely that you will be able to send emails externally.

As you see, there is a lot to check and eliminate as possible cause. By the way "System mail name" should not be `mysite.com` but `somehostname.mysite.com` - check the facts about [fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).